# Validating signed requests in C#

Tags: c#, oauth, opensocial, devdefined-oauth

I'm trying to validate incoming signed requests in my C# server.
The requests comes from a social platform(naver).
All I get from them is a certificate(below).

I'm using DevDefinedOAuth

http://code.google.com/p/devdefined-tools/

They have a wiki article on this subject.

http://code.google.com/p/devdefined-tools/wiki/OAuthSignatureValidation

and Here's my code:

```
        public static bool isValidRequest2( HttpListenerRequest request )
        {
            X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2();
            cert.Import( Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
@"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----" ) );

            DevDefined.OAuth.Framework.OAuthContext context = new DevDefined.OAuth.Framework.OAuthContext
            {
              //RawUri = request.Url,
              RawUri = CleanUri( request.Url ),
              Cookies = new NameValueCollection(),
              Headers = request.Headers,
              RequestMethod = request.HttpMethod,
              FormEncodedParameters = new NameValueCollection(),
              QueryParameters = new NameValueCollection( request.QueryString )
            };
            // do I need to set them manually?.. let's try..
            context.ConsumerKey = request.QueryString[ "oauth_consumer_key" ];
            context.Timestamp = request.QueryString[ "oauth_timestamp" ];
            context.Nonce = request.QueryString[ "oauth_nonce" ];
            context.Signature = request.QueryString[ "oauth_signature" ];

            var signer = new DevDefined.OAuth.Framework.Signing.OAuthContextSigner();

            DevDefined.OAuth.Framework.SigningContext signingContext = new DevDefined.OAuth.Framework.SigningContext();

            // use context.ConsumerKey to fetch information required for signature validation for this consumer.

            signingContext.Algorithm = cert.PublicKey.Key;
            //signingContext.ConsumerSecret; // if there is a consumer secret

            return ( signer.ValidateSignature( context, signingContext ) );
        }
```

And here's a sample request: (*I **changed the url a bit for security reasons***)

- Url: http://www.maxmax.co.cc:7677/?oauth_signature=b58RqdQ0Atnrvvy6Qi81BRv1fhmXIQEl3hY++Wi7kiinSOhWq7mluhsapEi/GvCUG6RjrYVowwTcoi MqqmVCasFlON7zU7Yyi8nOUAoClpoft0BXbT5xyNUmLOxTk47tmjWVMLniaOieVUEQLwP2yycH6hiWkf2gFWGsu9LHZbE=&oauth_nonce=14611349243983507&oauth _version=1.0&oauth_body_hash=2jmj7l5rSw0yVb/vlWAYkK/YBwk=&oauth_signature_method=RSA-SHA1&oauth_consumer_key=naver.com&xoauth_sign ature_publickey=http://nsocialcontainer.com/server/naver_socialapp_public.cer&xoauth_public_key=http://nsocialcontainer.com/server /naver_socialapp_public.cer&opensocial_owner_id=1400000000010946792&opensocial_app_id=25992&oauth_timestamp=1296334075
- HttpMethod: GET
- UserAgent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1
- QueryString

  - oauth_signature:b58RqdQ0Atnrvvy6Qi81BRv1fhmXIQEl3hY++Wi7kiinSOhWq7mluhsapEi/GvCUG6RjrYVowwTcoiMqqmVCasFlON7zU7Yyi8nOUAoClpoft0BX bT5xyNUmLOxTk47tmjWVMLniaOieVUEQLwP2yycH6hiWkf2gFWGsu9LHZbE=
  - oauth_nonce:14611349243983507 - oauth_version:1.0
  - oauth_body_hash:2jmj7l5rSw0yVb/vlWAYkK/YBwk=
  - oauth_signature_method:RSA-SHA1
  - oauth_consumer_key:naver.com
  - xoauth_signature_publickey:http://nsocialcontainer.com/server/naver_socialapp_public.cer
  - xoauth_public_key:http://nsocialcontainer.com/server/naver_socialapp_public.cer
  - opensocial_owner_id:1400000000010946792
  - opensocial_app_id:25992
  - oauth_timestamp:1296334075
- Headers

  - X-Forwarded-For:61.75.38.242
  - X-shindig-dos:on - Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
  - Host:www.maxmax.co.cc:7677
- body: ""

I get no error messages, no exceptions, but isValidRequest2() always returns 'false'
even with valid requests.

I must be using it wrong.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!!
If you have any questions on this question, please ask.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Sorry. the problem is that.. isValidRequest2() always returns 'false' even with valid requests.

Answer (score 0):

What version of the library are you using, perhaps try building from source off github here, if you haven't already:

https://github.com/bittercoder/DevDefined.OAuth

Also, it's worth noting that some opensocial platform implementations return Url's with additional ampersands (such as friendster used to) - see the bottom of this blog post here for details:

http://blog.bittercoder.com/PermaLink,guid,4f387bde-7ed6-480b-952b-bbc0ead9ebfb.aspx

If you are still having trouble, if you could provide a link to a full example of your consumer code (I suggest creating a gist: https://gist.github.com/gists) that would be really helpful in understanding what the problem is.

Comment: First, thanks!! I didn't know they moved to github. I built the source off from their old svn(http://devdefined-tools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/). I will get the new version from github after writing this. Looking at the url, I'm not getting additional ampersands. I believe I'm doing it wrong. I created a gist: https://gist.github.com/802808 .. testOAuth.WebServer.cs is the server w/ isValid(), isValid2() & isValid3(). OAuthbase.cs is from http://code.google.com/p/oauth/ (csharp version). I learned OAuthbase.cs from http://wiki.opensocial.org/index.php?title=Validating_Signed_Requests .

Comment: By the way, IsValid() uses OAuthbase, isValid2() uses DevDefined.OAuth, isValid3() uses OpenSocial .NET Client Library.